# Suppress SQLCMD messages

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

Would it be possible to suppress all `sqlcmd` messages output to the `cmd` window?

I am running a large script and it seems to be slowed down a lot with all the `Processed XXXX total records` messages.

The script is over 4Gb so there is a large amount of data.

Comment: Are you talking about N rows affected message or is your script itself printing those messages? Is routing the output to a file any more palatable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At the top of the script put the following

SET NOCOUNT ON

That will hide the n rows effected messages.

Answer (score 11):

You could pipe the results to NUL

```
C:\>sqlcmd -S localhost -d mydb -i C:\stuff.sql > NUL
```

I don't see any options in [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) to actually suppress output, just to redirect streams to files.